# How to mount /home/<my_user>/.ssh folder in devcontainer

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mount, vscode-devcontainer

I would like git to access to my .ssh folder with the keys while working inside devcontainer, I thought to use `runArgs` to mount `/home/<my_user>/.ssh` folder like this:

```
"runArgs": [
        "-v", "/home/<my_user>/.ssh:/home/.ssh:ro"
    ],
```

but I'm not sure how to get my user folder in the host machine of the devcontainer